# Youtube Data API: getting total comments, likes, dislikes

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have this issue.

I have a list of youtube channels I am polling from the API to get some stats daily.

- Total comments, likes and dislikes (all time and all videos)

I have implemented the below, it works, but it loops through every single video one at a time, hitting the API.

Is there a way to make one API call with several video IDs?

Or is there a better way to do this and get these stats?

```
#find stats for all channel videos - how will this scale?
def video_stats(row):
  videoid = row['video_id']
  query = yt.get_video_metadata(videoid)
  vids = pd.DataFrame(query, index=[0])
  df['views'] = vids['video_view_count'].sum()
  df['comments']  = vids['video_comment_count'].sum()
  df['likes'] = vids['video_like_count'].sum()
  df['dislikes'] = vids['video_dislike_count'].sum()
  return 'no'

df['stats'] = df.apply(video_stats, axis = 1)

channel['views'] = df['views'].sum()
channel['comments'] = df['comments'].sum()
channel['likes'] = df['likes'].sum()
channel['dislikes'] = df['dislikes'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id), you may cumulate in one [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint call the IDs of several different videos:

> **id**: string
>
> The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube video ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a video resource, the id property specifies the video's ID.

However, the code you have shown is too terse for to figure out a way of adapting it to such type of (batch) endpoint call.